# onchange doesn't fire in IE when window is blurred

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onchange

I've been googling like mad, but I cannot seem to find anything on the issue.

I have an input (type='text') for which I would like to fire some code onchange. My problem is, that onchange doesn't fire in IE, if while editing the value, the user clicks on some other window or tab. When the user comes back and leaves the input field, it is no longer a change. So the onchange never fires in this case even though the value has been changed by the user.
I tested the same thing in Chrome, where it works fine, but not in IE (tried with 9 and 11).

I also tested whether it fires onblur, which it does. So I guess it should be possible to do something with onblur instead...

Does anyone have a good idea how to do a relatively simple workaround to solve this rather annoying issue?

If relevant, the element looks like this:

```
<input type='text' value='1' onkeyup='if (event.keyCode==13) {jsFunction();}' onchange='jsFunction();'>
```

Comment: You can replace `onchange` with `oninput` that fires when a user types something. But it's better if you attach the events outside of the HTML code, HTML is markup, not functionality

Comment: See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks, I didn't know oninput existed.
But what do you mean I should attach the events outside of the HTML code? You mean it's better if I add onchange to the element in javascript?

Comment: Yeah put all your js code in a js file, you must use event listeners. I recommend jquery because its simplicity